# Flask wtf форма никогда не проходит валидацию

Tags: flask-wtf

Есть форма коммертария:

```
class CommentForm(FlaskForm):
    rating = IntegerField('Your rating (from 1 to 5)', validators=[DataRequired(),
                                                                   NumberRange(min=1, max=5)])
    comment = TextAreaField('Your comment', validators=[DataRequired(),
                                                        Length(min=5, max=255)])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

и метод в application.py:

```
@app.route('/book', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def book():
    if "user_id" in session:
        form = CommentForm()
        if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate_on_submit():
            print("!!!!")
            comment = db.execute("SELECT * FROM reviews WHERE (book_isbn=:isbn AND user_id=:user_id)",
                                 {'book_isbn': request.args.get('isbn'),
                                  'user_id': request.args.get('user_id')}).fetchone()
            #TODO
        book_data = db.execute(f"SELECT * FROM books WHERE isbn=:isbn", {"isbn": request.args.get("isbn")}).fetchone()
        greads_data = requests.get("https://www.goodreads.com/book/review_counts.json",
                            params={"key": "somekey", "isbns": book_data.isbn}).json()
        greads_book_data = greads_data['books'][0]
        if book_data:
            return render_template('book.html', book=book_data,
                                                average_rating=greads_book_data['average_rating'],
                                                work_ratings_count=greads_book_data['work_ratings_count'],
                                                form=form,
                                                user_id=session['user_id'])
        else:
            flash("Book is currently not available")
            return redirect(url_for('index'))
    else:
        return redirect(url_for('sign_in'))
```

Проблема в том, что блок

```
if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate_on_submit():
```

никогда не достигается, даже если в форме нет ошибок. Когда они там есть, они отображаются в форме на странице книги, когда их нет - в форме нет сообщений об ошибке. Почему при этом form.validate_on_submit() всегда возвращает false непонятно. Метод и параметра запроса верные, все проверил неоднократно. Заранее спасибо за помощь

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow in Russian! As the name implies, Russian is the working language of this site. Please either translate your question into Russian or [ask the same question on StackOverflow in English](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Your question may be closed soon, but it will most likely be reopened if you choose to translate it.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел проблему: {{ form.hidden_tag() }}